# pandas compare and put datas using two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes in python pandas like this:

df1 is raw dataset

df2 is the column information of df1

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
data_list = ['AA1','AAABB','AACCCDDDD', 'AACCCDDDDEEEEE','AA111','AA11222']
df1['DATA'] = data_list
```

df1 is the dataset of raw datas like this:

```
df1
-------------------
    DATA
-------------------
0   AA1
1   AAABB
2   AACCCDDDD
3   AACCCDDDDEEEEE
4   AA111
5   AA11222
```

df2 code :

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
data_list = ['AA1','AAAB','AACCC']
info_list = ['TYPE1','TYPE2','TYPE3']
size_list = [3, 4, 5]
df2['DATA_CLASS'] = data_list
df2['DATA_INFO']  = info_list
df2['DATA_SIZE']  = size_list
```

df2 has column information of df1's 'DATA'

df2 like this:

```
df2
-----------------------------
    DATA_CLASS  DATA_INFO   DATA_SIZE
0   AA1         TYPE1        3
1   AAAB        TYPE2        4
2   AACCC       TYPE3        5
```

I want to put in the 'DATA_INFO' in df1 using df2 ['DATA_CLASS','DATA_SIZE'].

so I wrote like this:

```
df1['DATA_INFO'] = ''
for idx, row in df2.iterrows():
    size = row['DATA_SIZE']

    df1.loc[df1.DATA.str[:size] == row['DATA_CLASS'], 'DATA_INFO'] =  row['DATA_INFO']
```

as a result df1 has new column 'DATA_INFO':

```
    DATA              DATA_INFO
----------------------------------
0   AA1               TYPE1
1   AAABB             TYPE2
2   AACCCDDDD         TYPE3
3   AACCCDDDDEEEEE    TYPE3
4   AA111             TYPE1
5   AA11222           TYPE1
```

but I'm facing a problem using dataframe .loc function.

it takes long time to process using if df1 has rows over 100,000 and df2 has rows over 10,000

I think dataframe's iterrows() is a major cause of the delay

Is there anyone having an idea how to solve put data types in df1 
not using .loc function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can first create new columns of `df1` with all possible substrings by [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) values of column `DATA_SIZE`, then [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) `df1` and [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.drop_duplicates.html). If ordering is important, use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
for i in df2['DATA_SIZE'].unique():
    #print i
    df1.loc[:, i] = df1['DATA'].str[:i]
print df1
             DATA    3     4      5
0             AA1  AA1   AA1    AA1
1           AAABB  AAA  AAAB  AAABB
2       AACCCDDDD  AAC  AACC  AACCC
3  AACCCDDDDEEEEE  AAC  AACC  AACCC
4           AA111  AA1  AA11  AA111
5         AA11222  AA1  AA11  AA112

df3 = df1.set_index('DATA').stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True).reset_index(name='MATCH')
print df3
              DATA  MATCH
0              AA1    AA1
1              AA1    AA1
2              AA1    AA1
3            AAABB    AAA
4            AAABB   AAAB
5            AAABB  AAABB
6        AACCCDDDD    AAC
7        AACCCDDDD   AACC
8        AACCCDDDD  AACCC
9   AACCCDDDDEEEEE    AAC
10  AACCCDDDDEEEEE   AACC
11  AACCCDDDDEEEEE  AACCC
12           AA111    AA1
13           AA111   AA11
14           AA111  AA111
15         AA11222    AA1
16         AA11222   AA11
17         AA11222  AA112
```

```
df = pd.merge(df3, df2, left_on="MATCH", right_on="DATA_CLASS").drop_duplicates()
df = df[['DATA','DATA_INFO']]
print df
             DATA DATA_INFO
0             AA1     TYPE1
3           AA111     TYPE1
4         AA11222     TYPE1
5           AAABB     TYPE2
6       AACCCDDDD     TYPE3
7  AACCCDDDDEEEEE     TYPE3


#if order of column DATA is important    
print df.set_index('DATA').reindex(df1.set_index('DATA').index).reset_index()
             DATA DATA_INFO
0             AA1     TYPE1
1           AAABB     TYPE2
2       AACCCDDDD     TYPE3
3  AACCCDDDDEEEEE     TYPE3
4           AA111     TYPE1
5         AA11222     TYPE1
```

Comment: Thank you! you are the best in my case. it's so fast to join two dataframes using your solution.